# Add labels to layer in CARTO.js (v4)

Tags: leaflet, carto, cartocss, css, carto.js

Does anyone know how to add labels (using a feature column such as "state") to a CARTO.js layer? This is how I have added the layer to my map:

```
const boundariesDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
      districtmunicipality2016
    `);
    const boundariesStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
      #layer {        
        ::outline {
          line-width: 1;
          line-color: #000000;
          line-opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    `);
    const boundaries = new carto.layer.Layer(boundariesDataset, boundariesStyle, {
        featureOverColumns: ['district_n']
    });
```

Ps, this line:

```
featureOverColumns: ['district_n']
```

Is used to select a feature to display in a pop up, using:

```
const popup = L.popup({ closeButton: false });
        boundaries.on(carto.layer.events.FEATURE_OVER, featureEvent => {
          popup.setLatLng(featureEvent.latLng);
          if (!popup.isOpen()) {
            popup.setContent(featureEvent.data.district_n);
            popup.openOn(map);
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add labels in CARTO.js using [CartoCSS text properties](https://carto.com/developers/styling/cartocss/#text) in your layer style object. Something like this should work:

```
#layer {
  polygon-fill: #826DBA;
  polygon-opacity: 0.9;
}
#layer::outline {
  line-width: 1;
  line-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-opacity: 0.5;
}
#layer::labels {
  text-name: [name];
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
  text-size: 10;
  text-fill: #FFFFFF;
  text-label-position-tolerance: 0;
  text-halo-radius: 1;
  text-halo-fill: #6F808D;
  text-dy: -10;
  text-allow-overlap: true;
  text-placement: point;
  text-placement-type: dummy;
}
```

You would need to replace the `name` field with your proper column name.